# convert ppt to PDF (error encountered)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, subprocess, powerpoint

Objective: Converting ppt to pdf using python 3.6.1

Scenario: MS Office is not installed in windows server

Code used:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time

def convert(src, dst):
    d = {'src': src, 'dst': dst}
    commands = [
        '/usr/bin/docsplit pdf --output %(dst)s %(src)s' % d,
        'oowriter --headless -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export %(dst)s %(src)s' % d,
    ]

    for i in range(len(commands)):
        command = commands[i]
        st = time.time()
        process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True) # I am aware of consequences of using `shell=True` 
        out, err = process.communicate()
        errcode = process.returncode
        if errcode != 0:
            raise Exception(err)
        en = time.time() - st
        print ('Command %s: Completed in %s seconds' % (str(i+1), str(round(en, 2))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = 'C:\xxx\ppt'
    dst = 'C:\xxx\ppt\destination'
    convert(src, dst)
```

Error Encountered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonFolder/ppt_to_pdf.py", line 134, in <module>
    convert(src, dst)
  File "C:/PythonFolder/ppt_to_pdf.py", line 123, in convert
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True) # I am aware of consequences of using `shell=True`
  File "C:\Python 3.6.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python 3.6.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
ValueError: embedded null character
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?
Or any other python library that will help in this case.

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Linux?

Comment: If you're running on Windows, I don't think the command `/usr/bin/docsplit pdf --output %(dst)s %(src)s` will convert the PPT, since it seems it's for Linux. Popen might be having trouble handling that command, causing that error.

Comment: i am running on windows. If that's the case is there any workaround?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running on Windows, the command `/usr/bin/docsplit pdf --output %(dst)s %(src)s` won't convert the PPT, since it seems it's for Linux. Popen might be having trouble handling that command, causing the error.

Converting a PPT to a PDF in the command line on Windows is kinda hard. I think your best bet is [to install LibreOffice and run with headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32583091/3011359). There's also [a SuperUser question on it](https://superuser.com/questions/641471/how-can-i-automatically-convert-powerpoint-to-pdf) where the asker ends up using C# interop libraries, but I think that requires Microsoft Office to be installed.

Thanks.